# Dataobject and Page relationships

Tags: silverstripe

http://www.silverstripe.org/archive/show/1638

The above post seems like it's what I should do but I just need some help sorting this out in my head.

Firstly, I need to create a relationship between a page (Owner, for example) and a dataobject (Car). An owner can create many cars which are linked to that one owner. However, I have another page (Garage) which can create cars that are linked to every owner. If an owner does not want one of these cars they reject it. I was thinking the manymanydataobjectmanager would be good for that bit.

Each owner should only be able to see the cars that relate directly to them within the CMS, not other peoples cars, so I was using dataobjectmanager and assigning permissions to the page using groups.

The thing that is really making this awkward is that when it's all set up I need to output JSON which will consist of the cars the owners created and the cars they accepted from the garage, not the ones they rejected. I'm thinking I need another table like the linked table but with a status column perhaps?

To clarify, my question is how do I create this mess in a constructive SilverStripe way? Is the approach I was taking correct or is there a better way?

Many thanks in advance and please tell me if I've been unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using silverstripe 3?
could you clarify what of the actions happen in the backend and what actions are possible for the user in the frontend?

maybe for your relations it could be better to use ModelAdmin:
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/modeladmin
It gives you the opportunity to manage relations without the Sitetree/Pages Overhead. For example creating a Sitetree Element just to have an Owner is not the best way - except if you really need an Owner represented as a real Page. Owner could be also just a Dataobject instead.

Especially if you want to output just JSON in the end you are maybe completely independent of Sitetree/Pages... then you could write a custom controller with a routing rule and which gives you back just the data that you need:
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller

regards,
Florian

Comment: I'm using 2.4.7.  I've figured out some things I just have one specific question now. Is it possible to pull existing information into a dataobjectmanager because I am having trouble doing so.  What I mean is I want the admin to see all cars in a dataobjectmanager (or something) and the user to see only the cars that relate specifically to them.

Comment: hey, i have not so much experience with dataobject manager. for what do you need it?

Comment: I have since solved this by using manymanydataobjectmanager for the admin page.  Thanks for your help. :)